# Javascript import package Failed to resolve module specifier

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import a module I have downloaded with npm.

My json file is:

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-web-app1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "NodejsWebApp1",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "node-pandas": "^1.0.5",
    "node-static": "^0.7.11",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
  },
}
```

I have my html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="module" src="functions.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <p>Welcome!</p>
    <button onclick="scraper()">CLICK</button>
    <label id="label">Reponse</label>
</body>

</html>
```

my functions.js file

```
import pd from 'node-pandas';
function scraper() {
    const s = pd.Series([1, 9, 2, 6, 7, -8, 4, -3, 0, 5])
    console.log(s);
    document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = 'A computer science portal for geeks';
}
```

and my server.js file:

```
var nStatic = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var file = new nStatic.Server(__dirname);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(port);
```

But when running the code I have the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "node-pandas".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I tried  but it gives another error also.

If I write:

```
import pd from './node-pandas';
```

or

```
import pd from '../node-pandas';
```

I get:

> GET http://localhost:1337/node-pandas net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

My project has this structure:

- myproject

  - server.js
  - functions.js
  - index.html
  - package.json
  - node_modules

    - node-pandas

And I am using visual studio 2019

Any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same issue (I'm a total beginner).

I installed via NPM a dependency and within that project they were using import statement like

```
import pd from './node-pandas';
```

instead of

```
import pd from './node-pandas.js';
```

So I had a situation where Live Server was hosting the javascript file on "http://localhost/scriptname.js" while the project was looking for that file instead on "http://localhost/scriptname" (without the .js extension)

I could off course add .js to the import statement, but then I would have to do that for ALL the import statements on all the files of this external project.

It's strange that there is not a lot of information about this error, but in summary:

- There exists something as Module Specifiers and Relative Import References: https://sbcode.net/threejs/module-specifiers/
- You can only use relative import references. If you want to use Module Specifiers, you need a tool to resolve those
- An example of such tool is WebPack. It will resolve all these import statement for you and generate one javascript file instead that you can add to your html file instead

Answer (score 0):

```
import pd from './node-pandas';
```

Also Check that do you have any default exports in your node-pandas or not.
If there is no default export in that case you have to use

```
import { moduleName } from './node-pandas';
```

Here module name would be exact same name by which it's exported and for multiple
imports you should seperate them using comma

Hope this solve your query

Comment: It does not work. I have created a project with visual studio and installed the package with npm. So I have no idea if there is a default export with node-pandas..

Answer (score 0):

```
const pd = require("node-pandas")
```

Using require instead of import keyword might work as import is es6 and es7 specific
on the other hand require is supported by regular js as of in Node projects

Comment: I get qnother error. functions.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at functions.js:2

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide the relative path to the module like 'assets/node-pandas/dist/node-pandas'

Answer (score -1):

```
import pd from 'node-pandas';
```

**## Here node-pandas module is in some kind of root directory ##**

I advise using  ./ or ../ before your module name,
Provided information is not enough to provide an solution